# How do I reset the boolean values in each method call?

Tags: java

I have this class,

```
public class Person {
    private static boolean validPerson = false;
    private static boolean invalidPerson = false;

    public PersonDTO getPersonInfo(long personId) {
        PersonDTO personDto = new this.PersonDTO();
        var personList = // get from API

        List<AddressDTO> addressDetails = personList.stream().map(p -> getAddressList(..supply input..).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        
        personDto.setIsValidPerson(validPerson);
        personDto.setIsInvalidPerson(invalidPerson);
        personDto.setAddressDetails(addressDetails);

        return personDto;

    }

    private static List<String> getDddressList(String personData) {
        if (personData == null) {
            invalidPerson = true;
        } else {
            validPerson = true;
            ...
            ... // process personData info to get addressData
        }

        return addressData;
    }
}
```

When I initially reload the page, then it returns the valid boolean data but when I reload the page, some of the boolean values are still the old ones.

For example, at the beginning of the call, value of `validPerson` will still be `true` instead of default value `false`.

How can I reset the boolean values each time `getPersonInfo` method gets called?

Comment: Those variables [shouldn't be static](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/108-static-is-a-swear-word) Nor should the method

Comment: I tried making it not static but still experienced the same behavior.

Comment: That should not be the case. Why do you have two `boolean` variables that are the opposite of each other btw? Also you seem to be mixing two distinct concepts: a bean and a DTO of that bean, in the same class

Comment: usually it is preferable to write `invalidPerson = (personData == null);` (and then there is no need to "*reset*" it)

Comment: @user16320675 variables names are just some random names that I have used to demonstrate what I am doing in real case. In my case, either one can be true or both can be true without depending on each other.

Comment: that doesn't change anything I wrote... actually not sure why you think that the names are relevant (for what I wrote) -- lets try different code: instead of `x = false; if (y == null) x = true;`, you *can* write just `x = (y == null);`  (assuming `boolean x`)

Answer (score -1):

Try this way. Make the variables non static and pass thesevariables from method 1 to 2, so you will not get the unrecognised variables error.

```java
public class Person {
    public PersonDTO getPersonInfo(long personId) {
        boolean validPerson = false;
        boolean invalidPerson = false;

        PersonDTO personDto = new PersonDTO();
        var personList = // get from API

        List<AddressDTO> addressDetails = personList.stream().map(p -> getAddressList(..supply input..)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        personDto.setIsValidPerson(validPerson);
        personDto.setIsInvalidPerson(invalidPerson);
        personDto.setAddressDetails(addressDetails);

        return personDto;
    }

    private List<String> getAddressList(String personData, boolean validPerson, boolean invalidPerson) {
        List<String> addressData = new ArrayList<>();

        if (personData == null) {
            invalidPerson = true;
        } else {
            validPerson = true;
            // Process personData info to get addressData
            // ...
        }

        return addressData;
    }
}
```